# doctrine - get next and prev record

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

just so i have some record allready fetched. I have date field 'created' and now I want to get next and prev record by date.

Got it working by:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

    $next = $qb->expr()->gt('a.created', ':date');
    $prev = $qb->expr()->lt('a.created', ':date');

    $prev = $qb->select('partial a.{id,title,created}')
        ->where($prev)
        ->setParameter('date', $date)
        ->orderBy('a.created', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    $next = $qb->select('partial a.{id,title,created}')
        ->where($next)
        ->setParameter('date', $date)
        ->orderBy('a.created', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

it working very well. But this is 2 question to database. I need one. I can do this by just join etc., but when there is no next or no prev I got just an empty array.

any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alexandr's response is close. When you query for `id < 2 LIMIT 1` it will return `1`, but if you query for `id < 5 LIMIT 1` this will also return `1`. That is because it returns `1, 2, 3, 4` and takes the first element, which is `1` rather than the needed `4`.

Just add `ORDER BY id DESC` to get the previous item. This will return `4, 3, 2, 1` and the `LIMIT 1` will return `4`, or the previous element.

```
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT id FROM users WHERE
        id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id > 2 LIMIT 1)
        OR
        id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id < 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)', $rsm);
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach to native SQL, when using an ORM Entity Repository.

```php
namespace EntityNamespace;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MyEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return array|int[]
     */
    public function filterNextPrevious($id)
    {
        $expr = $this->_em->getExpressionBuilder();
        $qbNext = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
           ->select(['MIN(a.id)'])
           ->where($expr->gt('a.id', ':id'));
        $qbPrevious = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->select(['MAX(b.id)'])
            ->where($expr->lt('b.id', ':id'));
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->select(['m.id'])
            ->where($expr->orX(
                $expr->eq('m.id', '(' . $qbNext->getDQL() . ')'),
                $expr->eq('m.id', '(' . $qbPrevious->getDQL() . ')')
            ))
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->addOrderBy('m.id', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();
       //optionally enable caching
       //$query->useQueryCache(true)->useResultCache(true, 3600);    

        return $query->getScalarResult();
    }
}
```

Resulting DQL:

```sql
SELECT m.id 
FROM EntityNamespace\Entity m 
WHERE m.id = (
    SELECT MIN(a.id) 
    FROM EntityNamespace\Entity a 
    WHERE a.id > :id
) 
OR m.id = (
    SELECT MAX(b.id) 
    FROM EntityNamespace\Entity b 
    WHERE b.id < :id
) 
ORDER BY m.id ASC
```

*(optionally use instead of querybuilder via `$this->_em->createQuery($DQL)`)*

Resulting Dataset:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5869"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5871"
  }
}
```

---

Another alternative to using the `WHERE IN()` condition is to use `SELECT` subqueries, and optionally add a total `COUNT()` to the base table.

This will allow you to assign the resulting value to an associated key and do away with the `ORDER BY` clause.

```php
$expr = $this->_em->getExpressionBuilder();
$next = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select($expr->min('a.id'))
    ->where($expr->gt('a.id', ':id'));
$previous = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->select($expr->max('b.id'))
    ->where($expr->lt('b.id', ':id'));
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->select('COUNT(o.id) as total')
    ->addSelect('(' . $previous->getDQL() . ') as previous')
    ->addSelect('(' . $next->getDQL() . ') as next')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->getQuery();

/* optionally enable caching
 * $query->useQueryCache(true)->useResultCache(true, 3600);
 */

return $query->getSingleResult();
```

Result DQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(o.id) as total, 
    (
     SELECT MAX(b.id) 
     FROM EntityNamespace\Entity b 
     WHERE b.id < :id
    ) as previous, 
    (
     SELECT MIN(a.id) 
     FROM EntityNamespace\Entity a 
     WHERE a.id > :id
    ) as next 
FROM EntityNamespace\Entity o
```

Resulting Dataset:

```
array(3) {
    ["total"]=>
    string(4) "63156"
    ["previous"]=>
    string(4) "5869"
    ["next"]=>
    string(4) "5871"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make it with native queries:

```
/** @var EntityManager $em */
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');

$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT id FROM users WHERE
        id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id > 2 LIMIT 1)
    OR
        id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id < 2 LIMIT 1)', $rsm);
$users = $query->execute();
```

in **$users** variable you will have following array:

```
[
    ['id' => 1]
    ['id' => 3]
]
```

More details here http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html