# Symfony, previous and next links

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with Symfony2.

I have to get links to the previous and next articles of loaded article.

for instance.:

I have 3 post (1, 2 and 3).

When I'm in Article 2 need to show links to articles 1 and 3 (previous and next)

Any idea how to do it efficiently?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

well the best hint i can give is to query for a date.

So the next article is the first one that is older and the prev article is the first one that is newer

Comment: I could also use the id.

I have not expanded enough my question to explain that my problem is with the approach to the PHP programming within the controller.

Whether using a arrayColletion or queries to databases.

Any idea on how to approach it with some sample code?

Thanks again

Comment: but you cant expect that its an ongoing number maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670769/doctrine-get-next-and-prev-record